# In Word 2010, how to remove the small black line in draft mode?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I've tried to Google ways to get rid of it, but couldn't find anything. It appears everytime I enter Draft mode.

**Example of the line, never mind the f.lux tint:**

[image: Example of the line, never mind the f.lux tint]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In draft mode, this line indicates "end of document". It isn't part of the text or page formatting, but of the view itself (and has been ever since Word 1.0 in 1989). As far as I know, you cannot disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Try highlighting the offending text and then right click on it.  You'll see the font option.  Click on that and see if any of the font options are checked; if so, eliminate them.